# Javascript prevent "undefined" value with dynamic array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic, undefined

I have dynamic form elements and trying to add values to input's value attribute which is coming from as a array. However sometimes there are no any data ,then javascript prints undefined to value area of the input element.

How can i check it and dont print undefined in dynamic element?

```
$("#test").append("<input type='text' name='first-test' class='form-control' value='"+testarray['first-test']+"' >
```

When we check the textbox , it shows "**undefined**" as a value.

Comment: Did you try `if (testarray['first-test'] != undefined)` ?

Comment: `(testarray['first-test'] || "")`

Comment: it corrupts the page when i add these statements in "append"

Comment: Arrays have *numeric* indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work

```
$("#test").append("<input type='text' name='first-test' class='form-control' value='"+(testarray['first-test']===undefined ? "Insert here what ever you want when it is empty.":testarray['first-test'])+"'>");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b51gq0mq/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example, we pass an array with objects into our function. For loop simply skips if value is not found.

```js
var yourArray = [
  { name: 'Janet' },
  { name: 'Jane', value: 1 },
  { name: 'Tom', value: 2 },
  { name: 'Kate', value: 3},
  { name: 'Mark' },
  { name: 'Tom' }
];

function addInputs(array) {
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var element = array[i];
    
    // Skips if no value found
    if (element.value === undefined) {
      continue;
    }   
    
    var html = '<input type="text" name="' + element.name + '" class="form-control" value="' + element.value + '" />';
    

    
    $('#test').append(html);
  }
};

addInputs(yourArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




<div id="test"></div>
```